# ¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda de un valor char en una matriz en C++?

Tags: c++, matrices, array

Lo que pasa es que estoy realizando un programa, el cual capturé nuevos clientes, ventas, pagos y búsqueda. El problema es que me piden que busque por nombre y no por localidad e intentado pero no entiendo cómo se hace.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    HANDLE hcon=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwpos;
    dwpos.X=x;
    dwpos.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwpos);
}
class cliente
{
    public:
    char nom[50][10];
    float saldo[50];
    int c;

    void ventas();
    void pagos();
    void registro();
    void buscar();
};
void cliente::ventas()
{
    int x,y,z,m;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"ventas\n";
    cout<<"que numero de la lista tiene asignado el cliente?\n";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"precio del objeto a vender al cliente?\n";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"con cuanto paga el cliente?\n";
    cin>>y;
    z=y-x;
    if(z>=0)
    {
        cout<<"el cambio es $"<<z;
    }
    else if(z<0)
    {
        z=z*-1;
        cout<<"debe $"<<z<<"\n";
        saldo[m-1]=z;
    }
    system("pause");
}
void cliente::pagos()
{
    int x,m,y;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"pagos\n";
    cout<<"que numero de la lista tiene el cliente?\n";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"cantidad a abonar?\n";
    cin>>x;
    saldo[m-1]=saldo[m-1]-x;
    if(saldo[m-1]<0)
    {
        y=saldo[m-1]*-1;
        cout<<"\nsu cambio es $"<<y<<"\n";
        saldo[m-1]=0;
    }
    else if(saldo[m-1>=0])
    {
        cout<<"\ntodavia debe es $"<<saldo[m-1]<<"\n";
    }
    system("pause");
}
void cliente::registro()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"NOMBRE:";
    cin>>nom[c];
    c++;
    cout<<"nombre guardado exitosamente\n";
    system("pause");
}
void cliente::buscar()
{
    int x;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"que localidad tiene?\n";
    cin>>x;
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(5,0);cout<<"nombre";
    gotoxy(25,0);cout<<"debe";
    gotoxy(5,1);cout<<nom[x-1];
    gotoxy(25,1);cout<<saldo[x-1]<<"\n";
    system("pause");
}
class vip:public cliente //la clase base se debe declar como "public"
{
    public:
    float puntos[50];
    void descuentos();
};
void vip::descuentos()
{

}
cliente cl;
vip vp;
int main()
{
    int op;
    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\t MENU PRINCIPAL\n\n\n";
        cout<<"1.-REGISTRAR\n";
        cout<<"2.-BUSCAR\n";
        cout<<"3.-VENTAS\n";
        cout<<"4.-PAGOS\n";
        cout<<"5.-SALIR\n";
        cin>>op;
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                cl.registro();
                break;
            case 2:
                cl.buscar();
                break;
            case 3:
                cl.ventas();
                break;
            case 4:
                cl.pagos();
                break;
        }
    }while(op!=5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer la lista y, para cada elemento, comprobar si el nombre del registro correspondiente coincide con el buscado. Esto se puede conseguir con un `for` y un `if`:

```
string nombre_buscado;
std::cin >> nombre_buscado;

int i;
for( i=0; i<c; i++ )
{
  if( nom[i] == nombre_buscado )
    break;
}

if( i < c )
{
  // Ya has encontrado el registro que buscas
  // ...
}
else
{
  std::cout << "No se encuentra el registro.\n";
}
```

Hay profesores a los que no les gustan los `break`... sin problema

```
for( i=0; i<c && nom[i] != nombre_buscado; i++ ) ; // importante el punto y coma final

if( i < c )
  // ...
```